# Angular flatten inner array

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to get a value from nested array from a Form Values

[['A'], ['B']]-- from this array

['A','B'] --trying to get value like this

stackblitz example
  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4d5vfj-p5adyk?file=main.ts

```
  <button (click)="addNewChipList()">Add new Chip</button><br><br>

       <form [formGroup]="myForm">
       <ng-container formArrayName="names"
      *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('names').controls; let i = index;">
        <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" [formGroupName]="i">
           <mat-chip-list #chipList >
         <mat-chip *ngFor="let val of item.value.val"
    [selectable]="selectable"
    [removable]="removable"
    (removed)="removeChip(item, val)">
    {{val}}
    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
  <input [placeholder]="item.value.name"
    [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
    [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
    [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
    (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addChip($event, item)">
     </mat-chip-list>
    <mat-error>Atleast 1 name need to be added</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
            </ng-container>

           <button (click)="save()">save</button><br><br>
        </form>
```

component.ts

The componet file where I am trying to get form value

```
         export class ChipListValidationExample implements OnInit {
         @ViewChild('chipList') chipList: MatChipList;
        public myForm: FormGroup;

       // name chips
          visible = true;
          selectable = true;
          removable = true;
          addOnBlur = true;
       readonly separatorKeysCodes: number[] = [ENTER, COMMA];

   // data
     data = {
          names: [this.initName('name1'), this.initName('name2', [['A'], 
      ['B']])]
   }

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
 this.myForm = this.fb.group({
   names: this.fb.array(this.data.names, this.validateArrayNotEmpty)
      });
      }

  ngOnInit() {
 this.myForm.get('names').statusChanges.subscribe(
  status => this.chipList.errorState = status === 'INVALID'
         );
      }

   initName(name: string, val: string[] = []): FormControl {
     return this.fb.control({ name, val});
         }

            validateArrayNotEmpty(c: FormControl) {
    if (c.value && c.value.length === 0) {
       return {
         validateArrayNotEmpty: { valid: false }
     };
       }
      return null;
        }

         addChip(event: MatChipInputEvent, ctrl: FormControl): void {
        const input = event.input;
            const value = event.value;

// Add name
        if ((value || '').trim()) {
          const control = ctrl;
      control.value.val.push(value.trim());
         console.log(control.value);
                }

      // Reset the input value
      if (input) {
       input.value = '';
         }
           }

       removeChip(ctrl, val) {
     const idx = ctrl.value.val.findIndex(item => item === val);
     ctrl.value.val.splice(idx, 1);
      }

          addNewChipList() {
        const items = this.myForm.get('names') as FormArray;
        items.push(this.initName(`name${items.length + 1}`));
         }

        save(){
        console.log("FormValues",this.myForm.value)
        }

        }
```

I am trying to get the form value as ['A','B']

Comment: Why are you setting the initial value of the form in the nested array in the first place? Is an API returning the data to you in this format?

Comment: Yes..I am getting an array

Comment: If it's coming as nested fields from the API, then wouldn't the API also accept it in a nested format? If not, then can you consider transforming the API response before setting the data? It would be easier that way.

Comment: This question looks like it can use some serious editing. Most of the code you provided was totally irrelevant to the question you are asking.

Comment: If you see the stackblitz example, In console I am getting for val attribute val: Array[2]
0: "A"
1: "B"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object .. I want to retrieve only the val values... something like this['Á','B']not the json object . How can I retrive that even though let say it is not a nested array[['A'], ['B']]?

Answer (score 0):

Flattening some arrays is a trivial task with plain JS. Using [`Array.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), you can do this in one line.

> The flat() method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> var newArray = arr.flat([depth]);
>
> **Parameters**
>
> depth Optional
>
> The depth level specifying how deep a nested array structure should be flattened. Defaults to 1.
>
> **Return value**
>
> A new array with the sub-array elements concatenated into it.

```js
//one level deep
var x = [['A'], ['B']];
console.log(x.flat());
// => ['A', 'B']

//2 levels deep
var y = [[['A', 'B'], ['C']], ['D']];
console.log(y.flat(2));
// => ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```